# How to evict Cache based on Cache Name passed

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I am calling fetchCatchAndClear method where I am passing List and it consists of cache names. Can someone help me how to iterate over the list and clear the cache based on the Cache Name coming from List of String. Also if the list is empty I should clear all the caches present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather simple approach which sticks to the `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` could be the following:

```
List<String> cacheNames = List.of("aCache", "anotherCache"); // the list you are passing in
CacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager(); // any cache manager you are injecting from anywhere

// a simple iteration, exception handling omitted for readability reasons
cacheNames.forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
```

Evicting all caches is also that simple, except that you have to query the relevant cache names from the very same cache manager:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
Collection<String> cacheNames = cacheManager.getCacheNames();

cacheNames.forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
```

If you just want to evict a single cache entry you could either do it programmatically like:
`cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).evict(cacheKey);` or annotation-based like

```
@CacheEvict(value = "yourCacheName", key = "#cacheKey")
public void evictSingleCacheValue(String cacheKey) {
}


@CacheEvict(value = "yourCacheName", allEntries = true)
public void evictAllCacheValues() {
}
```

Comment: Please verify if I could write something of this type -                                            public List<String> fetchCache(List<String cacheNames) {   
CacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager(); 
if(!cacheNames.isEmpty()) {  
 cacheNames.forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());  
 } else{  
 Collection<String> cacheNames = cacheManager.getCacheNames();   
 cacheNames.forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
 } 
 return cacheNames;

Comment: I didnot understand what difference it makes in clearing cache as a whole and clearing by specific name. Let me know if the above code will solve my purpose.

Comment: Also how about using annotation @CacheEvict for both cases

Comment: Yes the code in your comment is the same like the one that I provided, I just omitted the surounding method definition. You can use it this way. Remember both variants clear the whole caches. If you just want to evict certain cache entries, then use `cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).evict(cacheKey)`. For `@CacheEvict`, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thankx I have added the same code but now my doubt is that .getCacheNames are coming as empty. I have a class where Iam using Cacheable annotaion giving the cache names. Is there any link between those two, I mean how will CacheManager identifies the Cacheable methods and collect info from it.

Comment: Well the usage of `SimpleCacheManager` is just an example and thus contains no caches out-of-the-box. You have to use the exact `CacheManager` which is configured in your Spring Boot app. You should `@Autowired` or `@Inject` it. But this is another question, if this is your last issue. I'd be glad to help on that fact too. For now please do not forget to upvote or accept this answer here which covers mainly the issue of evicting caches.

Comment: Please find below steps where I am facing issue with the code given by you: 1) I have passed a cache name. Code works well. 2) when I didnot pass anything then ideally cacheManager.getCacheNames should give all caches which are there in @Cacheable method. But it is not. Also it is taking the name which I passed in Step 1 for clearing.

Comment: It seems to be a weird behaviour but need your immediate help if you can. To your previous comments, yes I am Autowiring CacheManager. Thanx again.

Comment: Ok to be clear of any misunderstanding: A `@Cacheable`-annotated method is used to put items into the cache. This has on the first hand nothing to do with your method described above in which you want to perform your eviction. Maybe this hint makes it clearer for you: The following code `cacheManager.getCacheNames()` gives you always any cache names that are configured in your app, regardless if they are really used in any `@Cacheable`-annotated method.